# Not able to complete fillable forms

Tags: microsoft-word

My company sent me a word document with fillable fields.  I am unable to resave the document to send back because I do not have word 2013 on my laptop.  Is there a work around?

Comment: What version of Word do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Save As?

Try choosing the most current .doc or .docx file type supported by your word processor.

Hopefully your company will be able to use the saved file that you send back to them.